# rect on top of quantmod series is off when changing window size

Tags: r, quantmod

i'm trying to draw a rectangle on top of a chart series drawn with `quantmod`.

```
> s<-get(getSymbols('phmd'))["2012:"]
> d<-findSupport(s,p=5,threshold=1)
> d
       low     high cnt        std
1 14.79000 14.85292   2 0.04448880
2 13.27222 13.31500   2 0.03024846
3 13.09000 13.15000   2 0.04242641
4 14.12000 14.20583   2 0.06069333
5 12.30222 12.38421   2 0.05797449
6 11.38269 11.43200   2 0.03486580
> chartSeries(s)
> u <- par("usr")
> rect(u[1],d[,'low'],u[2],d[,'high'],col=rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.5),border=0)
```

the rectangles being drawn are way off when changing the window size.
why is that and how can i overcome this ?
please assist, Thanks.

Comment: Wat do you mean by way off? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: take a look here [link](http://i.imgur.com/8BtAGIm.png). as you can see, there is a difference between the two window sizes, and, the lines are not drawn in the right place (take for example 11.38-11.43 which clearly does no exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know very well `quantmod`. But I think you must `add_XXX` functions which add information to the plot object (chob) and re-draw it. see `addLines` for example.

That's said, when I use `chart_Series` the experimental function, I don't have a problem when I re-size the window.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks man. i changed it to chart_Series and it did work fine with the resize and with the rect (there was no need for redrawing the chob). just one thing, do you happen to know why, when using the new function with the rect, it does not paint it with the color i specified ? (the old version did ... ) Thanks.

Comment: @haki what do you get as color? and what do you get when you remove the alpha part of your rgb color? it said in the documentation to be careful with alpha hen you use `chart_Sereis`...

Comment: i'm getting no color - just a border. when i remove the alpha it works fine. but, it comes out over the chart so it hides the candles. i couldn't find any z-index property so i tried using transparency instead.

Comment: @haki .I have to go out now..hope someone else can help you otherwise I ll take a look when I come back.

Comment: @haki I update my answer using the chart. For me it looks good. you can see the candles.

Comment: you've used the exact same syntax with the rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.5) ?

Comment: @haki yes..`rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.5)`.